# HTML, JS random code generator is not working

Tags: javascript, html, random

So I have this code for this class project that I am doing I have my random number generator attach to the **current flow** submit button and the results of the random number generator are supposed to go in the **water main information** placeholder. The numbers do pop up for a split second but then they disappear. What am I doing wrong?

```js
function refreshPage() {
  document.getElementById("ref").value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 70000) + 10000;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #87CEEB;
  color: #fff;
}

.header {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<form name="" class="">
  <fieldset>
    <div style="text-align:center; padding:.5em; margin-bottom:2em;">
      <span style="border:1px solid #ccc;text-align:center; font-size:2em;background:#0099FF;padding:.5em; clear:both;">
     National Water Company</span><br/>
      </br><span style="border:1px solid #ccc;text-align:center; font-size:20px;background:#0099FF; padding:.5em; clear:both;">
     System Damage Tracking, Water Loss Reporting. Leakage and Pipes Damage Reporting</span>
    </div>

    <div style="text-align:left; padding:.5em; margin-bottom:2em; width:40%; float:left;">
      <span style="width:1em; font-size:1.5em;">Water Main Information</span>
      <input id="ref" type="text" name="" style=" font-size:1.5em; width:160px;" /><br/>
      <input type="submit" name="" style="font-size:1.5em;background:#0099FF" Value="current flow" onClick="refreshPage()" />
    </div>
    <div style="text-align:left; padding:.5em; margin-bottom:2em;">
      <span style="width:10px; font-size:1.5em;">Customer Consumption </span>
      <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Name" style=" font-size:1.5em; width:160px;" />
      <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Address" style=" font-size:1.5em; width:160px;" />
      <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Location" style=" font-size:1.5em; width:160px;" /><br/>
      <input type="submit" name="" placeholder="" style="font-size:1.5em;background:#0099FF" Value="History" />
    </div>
    <div style="text-align:left; padding:.5em; margin-bottom:2em; width:50%; float:left;">
      <span style="width:1em; font-size:1.5em;">Request Incident</span>
      <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Name" style=" font-size:1.5em; width:150px;" />
      <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Phone" style=" font-size:1.5em; width:150px;" />
      <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Location" style=" font-size:1.5em; width:150px;" /><br/>
      <input type="submit" name="" placeholder="" style="font-size:1.5em;background:#0099FF" Value="History" />
    </div>
    <div style="text-align:left; padding:.5em; margin-bottom:2em;">
      <span style="width:1em; font-size:1.5em;">Differencing Data</span>
      <input type="text" name="" placeholder="00,000 l" style=" font-size:1.5em; width:160px;" /><br/>
      <input type="submit" name="" style="font-size:1.5em;background:#0099FF" Value="History" />
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: what do you mean pop up for a split second? probably because the JS ran and then you actually submit the page, thats why its showing a little bit then disappears. if you want to prevent this from happening, just add `return false` on the function

Comment: there is no php here

Comment: or probably use a `<button type="button>`, then won't make an actual form submission

Comment: @Ghost i am sorry but where would i but the return false this is my first class in coding and thank you for your help

Comment: Change `<input type="submit"` to `<input type="button"`

Comment: @Ghost - if you return false you need to change to  `onClick="return refreshPage()"` - easier to just make it a button

Comment: thank you guys for your help doing what mplungjan said made it work thanks again

Comment: just follow @mplungjan 's comment, it should answer everything, its doing an actual form submission, thats why its reloading again